# (Co)different ideal is divisorial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a normal ring $A$. Denote $F$ the fractional field of $A$. Suppose $K/F$ is a separable extension, and denote $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $K$. We know that $(x,y)\mapsto\operatorname{Tr}_{K/F}(xy)$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form $K\times K\to F$, and denote $M^*=\{\,u\in K\,\vert\,\forall b\in M\colon\operatorname{Tr}_{K/F}(bu)\in A\,\}$ for every $A$-module $M\subseteq K$. We note that $\operatorname{Tr}_{K/F}(B)\subseteq A$ by normality, thus $B\subseteq B^*$. On the other hand, there exists a free $A$-module $E\subseteq B$ of rank $[K:F]$, therefore $B^*\subseteq E^*$, hence $B^*/A$ is finite and thus $B^*$ is a fractional ideal of $B$, which is called the codifferent ideal of $B$ w.r.t. $A$. This is a known argument.

An ideal $J\subseteq B$ is divisorial if and only if $\operatorname{Ass}_B(B/J)$ consists of prime ideals of height $1$, i.e. the prime ideals that belong to $J$ (in the primary decomposition) are all of height $1$. <del>More generally, a fractional ideal $J\subseteq K$ is divisorial if and only if there exists $c\in K$ such that $cJ\subseteq B$ and $cJ$ is divisorial. It's verified by Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem that the definition doesn't depend on choices of $c$. (I hope I didn't misunderstand anything.)</del>

---

**EDIT:** More generally, a fractional ideal $J$ of $B$ is divisorial if there exists a finite number of prime ideals of height $1$: $P_1,\dotsc,P_n$, associated with $n$ integers $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n$, such that $x\in J$ if and only if $v_{P_i}(x)\ge\alpha_i$ for all $i$, and for $P\not\in\{P_1,\dotsc,P_n\}$ with height $1$, we have $v_P(x)\ge0$. $v_P$ is the valuation associated to $P$ with height $1$, by virtue of normality of $A$, as well as that of $B$.

---

It's claimed on Serre's *Local Algebra* that

> It is **easy** to see that it (namely, $B^*$) is a divisorial ideal of $B$ (**EDIT:** in the original text, it's $L$ corresponding to $K$ here. I have changed letters and notations).

I cannot conceive a proof for this proposition. It seems to me that we need a good local characterization of divisorial ideals, since dimension theory in local rings is better, then localize the proposition and check whether $B^*$ satisfies. I don't know how to proceed.

Any idea? Thanks.

**POSTSCRIPT:** It seems to me that the definition of divisorial is closely related to Weil divisors in geometry, and that $J$ is an invertible sheaf associated to a Weil divisor. However, since I don't know anything more than some definitions in geometry, I cannot give any more information.